# why are there different arguments in this javascript function

Tags: javascript

I saw this function , though it works fine but I am bit puzzled about the function expressions. Here is the code

```
      mapForEach(arr, fn)   {
          var newArr = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)  {
              newArr.push(fn(arr[i]))

         }
         return newArr;
      }
```

can anybody explain to nme what this rather complicated code is actually doing?

Comment: **What the code is doing?** => Same as `var newArr = arr.map(function(el) {
    return fn(el);
});` Basically, this function is calling `fn` for each of the element in the array and returning the updated array.

Comment: it returns a new array with the result of the function calling on every element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have `var array = [1, 2, 3, 5];` and then run `var array2 = mapForEach(array, function(i) { return i * 2; })`
`array2` would then contain `[2, 4, 6, 10]`.

So it returns a new array where you have the ability to modify each record with a function

Answer (score 1):

mapForEach enumerates an array and calls a supplied function on each element.

example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(mapForEach(a, (x) => x * 2));
```

would create a new array with the values (and output to console):

`[2, 4, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is an implementation of javascript native array function `map`, which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

More info about mentioned function you can find here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map